# Arduino Timer loop

Tags: c++, loops, arduino, counter, arduino-ide

I'm Writing some code for my Arduino that displays "Timer(counts from 1-100)" then displays "Interrupts: b"( b acts as a placeholder for how many times it looped)It counts to 100 then prints out my else statement but it doesn't loop and my b value just keeps incrementing. Where am i going wrong?

```
    void loop() {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

         if(a != 100){
    
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("Timer");
          lcd.print("");
          a++;
          lcd.print(a); 
          delay(10);
          lcd.clear();
          
        }
        else{
    //
          b++;
          lcd.print("Interrupt");
          
          lcd.print(b);
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();
          
    //      
    //   
       }
    }
```

Comment: I fixed my answer, now it seems to work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `a` and `b` on the beginning of the `loop()`, the loop function is called every time, so your `a` and `b` are cleared every time. probably you have to define then out of the loop function.
Edit: In my example I declared the variables inside `setup()` function, as the guy who comment my answer said, it declares a variable only in the scope of that function, you actually need to declare it out of any function.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
void loop() {
     if(a != 100){
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Timer");
      lcd.print("");
      a++;
      lcd.print(a); 
      delay(10);
      lcd.clear();
    }
    else{
      b++;
      lcd.print("Interrupt");
      lcd.print(b);
      delay(1000);
      lcd.clear();
      a=0;
   }
}
```

Edit 2: Actually, your code don't do what you want. It counts 1 to 100 one time, then starts incrementing and printing `b`. You have to clear the `a` variable in your else statement to it starts counting again. I tested the code in Tinkercad and now it seems to work.
Code used in Tinkercad:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
void loop() {

     if(a != 100){
      a++;
       Serial.println(a);
       delay(10);
    }
    else{
      b++;
      Serial.println(b);
      delay(1000);
      a = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Now you're just defining a variables in `setup` that cannot be accessed from any other function.

Comment: Even when i declare them outside the setup and loop method my program just stays on the else statement and starts incrementing b with no loop?

Comment: I edited the answer, thank you. That should fix it.